# How to refresh all monitors in Eclipse memory viewer?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

When debugging code in eclipse, if I set up memory monitors for pointers in one debugging session, if I restart the debugger the memory monitors are still there, but I have to manually right click and refresh each monitor for it to show updated information, even though the data in memory it is monitoring gets updated during debugging.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIT71.png)

Is there a way to refresh all monitors at the same time?

Comment: You are talking about C or C++, not about Java or something else, right? Is this the current version of Eclipse and CDT?

Comment: The first comment is correct. Please add the Eclipse version and the target language.

Comment: @howlger This is a modified version of eclipse for some embedded system, called xtensa. I don't know which version of eclipse is it derived from though, but it's for C/C++ and not java.  In the picture that I uploaded, the "Refresh memory block" option on the right click menu is what I want to have happen for all monitors. I thought may be there was a general way of doing this in all eclipse

Comment: Are you talking about the [_Memory_ view](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_memoryview.htm)? On which Eclipse version and Eclipse CDT version is xtensa based? Maybe a screenshot that is not cropped that much would be more helpful.